# Example of a name that is not mapped in Unicode code points

Tags: unicode

The article "[Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)" lists 40 assumptions that are made about names.

There is a particular one that I am finding difficult to imagine:

> 11. People’s names are all mapped in Unicode code points.

What is an **example of such a name**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This woman's given name](http://en.rocketnews24.com/2014/02/13/japanese-woman-celebrates-100th-birthday-boggles-netizens-with-her-name/) is unrepresentable in Unicode:

> hentaigana means an “alternative kana” or different way of writing existing letters. The characters in hentaigana have largely fallen by the wayside but can sometimes be seen in places such as restaurant signs.
>
> In the case of this centenarian’s name, it’s a now-defunct way of writing “to” and derived from the kanji (登) which means “climb.” Someone managed to track down the font information for this one too.
>
> [image: Image of the glyph above]

There are quite a few instances where personal names that use extremely rare or historical forms of Chinese characters are not yet representable in Unicode. These slowly come to the attention of the IRG or Unicode Consortium via. "Urgently Needed Character" proposals. For example:

- [IRG N2068](http://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~irg/irg/irg44/IRGN2068_UTC_UNC.pdf) documents a Hanja character approved for use in Korean names.
- [IRG N2078](http://appsrv.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~irg/irg/irg44/IRGN2078_Japan_UNC_Proposal.pdf) documents five Kanji characters to be used on Japanese residence cards.

There are also living languages used by small communities of people that are not yet supported in Unicode (and thus neither are the names of its speakers). For example characters for supporting the [Ik language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ik_language) were only added in Unicode 8.0 (June 2015).

Answer (score 1):

The musician also known as [Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_(musician)) for some time used the stage name [image: (image showing the "love symbol")] (which I have represented here using an image, for obvious reasons). This single-character name consists purely of the "love symbol", a character which does not feature in any human language, is not representable in Unicode, and [never will be](https://parkerhiggins.net/2013/01/writing-the-prince-symbol-in-unicode/).

Comment: "... and never will be" - it's not entirely true that Unicode doesn't encode personal symbols and logos, I know at least one:  :)

Comment: @mojuba: a rectangle crossed through with an X? ;) An image would be worth a thousand words here.

Comment: @Piskvor if you are not joking, it's Apple's logo. I just realized that it's not standardized, it's in Unicode's private space, so yes, Unicode sticks to its principles :)

Comment: @mojuba He's not joking. On my Android phone, it's a rectangle with an X through it. On my Windows PC, from which I'm replying now, it's an empty rectangle. I guess that Mac system fonts provide whatever glyph it is that you're seeing.

Comment: Not displayed in FF/Linux, not displayed in IE, not displayed in SE Android app, no Apple logos for me! ;)